# How many of these numbers contain the digits $3$ and $5$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose that repetitions are not allowed.

There are $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 $ numbers with $4$ digits , that can be formed from the digits $1,2,3,5,7,8$.

How many of them contain the digits $3$ and $5$?

I thought that I could subtract from the total number of numbers those,that do not contain $3 \text{ and } 5$.I thought that the latter is equal to $4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2$,because then we can only use the numbers $1,2,7,8$.

So,the result would be $6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3-4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2=336$,but I found in my textbook an other result..

Is the way I did it wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the idea is correct. but you committed a common mistake, you $\underline{can}$ do it using the inclusion-exclusion principles, but you need to apply it twice.

What you did is take the total and substract the numbers that don't contain $\underline{both}$ $3$ or $5$. What you needed to substract is the numbers that don't contain at least one of them.

To calculate how many numbers fail to contain either $3$ or $5$ we can add the numbers that don't contain $3$ and the numbers that don't contain $5$. This gives us $5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2+5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2=240$ But notice you counted the elements that don't contain both $3$ and $5$ twice so you need to substract $4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=24$ so you get $216$ numbers that can fail to satisfy any of those conditions.

Finally you get $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3-216=144$

Comment: So,from the total number of 4-digit numbers,do I have to subtract  the numbers that contain 3 and not 5 and the numbers that contain 5 and not 3?

Comment: and also the numbers that don't contain either of them

Comment: Ok..I understand...Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think they mean the number of 4 digit numbers which contain both 3 and 5 together. In your case you have not subtracted numbers which may contain 3 and not 5 or numbers which may contain 5 and not 3.

Comment: I understand...Thank you very much!!!